# setup.h no such file or directory

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

Hello I am trying to build wxWidgets 3.0 for use with code blocks. When I run the command given on the manual

mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 CXXFLAGS=-fno-keep-inline-dllexport

It says an error include \include/setup/.h:121:27: fatal error:
../../../lib/vc_x64_lib/mswu/wx/setup.h

It also says

```
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.4\build\msw>mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1 CXXFLAGS=-fno-keep-inline-dllexport
if not exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu mkdir ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu
gcc -c -o gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o  -O2 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -DNDEBUG -I..\..\include -I..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu -D__WXMSW__  -D_UNICODE   -MTgcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o -MFgcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o.d -MD -MP ../../src/regex/regcomp.c
In file included from ..\..\include/wx/platform.h:183:0,
                 from ..\..\include/wx/defs.h:27,
                 from ../../src/regex/regcustom.h:39,
                 from ../../src/regex/regguts.h:38,
                 from ../../src/regex/regcomp.c:33:
..\..\include/wx/setup.h:12:6: error: #error "This file should only be included when using Microsoft Visual C++"
     #error "This file should only be included when using Microsoft Visual C++"
      ^
In file included from ..\..\include/wx/version.h:16:0,
                 from ..\..\include/wx/setup.h:19,
                 from ..\..\include/wx/platform.h:183,
                 from ..\..\include/wx/defs.h:27,
                 from ../../src/regex/regcustom.h:39,
                 from ../../src/regex/regguts.h:38,
                 from ../../src/regex/regcomp.c:33:
..\..\include/wx/setup.h:113:31: error: pasting "/" and "vc_x64_lib" does not give a valid preprocessing token
         wxCONCAT6(../../../lib/, wxLIB_SUBDIR, /, wxTOOLKIT_PREFIX, wxSUFFIX, /wx/setup.h)
```

The manual I’m following is : http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=WxWindowsQuickRef

Comment: Did you just posted a photo of your monitor instead just copying the text?

Comment: it was much was giving errors on my phone as I   was trying to post. Fixed it now

Comment: I'm sure you did something more than strictly what is said in that wiki. Perhaps you first used `makefile.vc` instead of `makefile.gcc`. Remove `....lib\gcc_dll\mswu`  and `...build\msw\gcc_whatever` and try again.

Comment: Still giving the same error

Comment: Weird. Copy  `include/wx/msw/setup0.h` to `include/wx/msw/setup.h`. Then remove the directories I posted. Then execute the command line again, I'd add the directive `CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11"`

Comment: Do I mean remove the zero from setup0.h ?

Comment: I've posted exactly filenames. BTW, what gcc version is your mingw? And what did you do extra from the instructions?

Comment: My gcc is 3.82. The only other thing I did was to install MinGW / gcc because a source told me that. I never needed it to compile my c++ programs before because codeblocks had it embedded

Comment: All there is no setup0.h

Answer (score 1):

You must have copied the file `include/msvc/wx/setup.h` to `include/wx/setup.h` manually, there is no other explanation for this file being there. You must not do it and now you need to remove the file you created and undo any other changes you may have done for the build to work.

Answer (score 0):

If anything you try still gives errors then follow these instructions:

1. Remove the whole of the wxWidgets folder, in your case
   `C:\wxWidgets-3.0.4`
2. Re-install wxWidgets, even in that same directory
3. Remove anything related to your old gcc (likely a dir and the PATH var, see below), and download an install a more recent version of gcc. From [Mingw 32
   mingw-get-setup.exe](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/downloads/68260/mingw-get-setup.exe/),
   from [Mingw 64](http://mingw-w64.org) or from [TDM combined
   32/64](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download/). You will need to set this compiler as the default one to C::B later, for your app.
4. Add if needed your `mingw/bin` dir to the Windows PATH environment
   var.
5. Open an command box window and copy&paste this line:

   > mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release UNICODE=1 USE_OPENGL=1
   >   CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11 -fno-keep-inline-dllexport"

Note I've removed the MONOLITHIC=1 flag, sometimes it's a source of problems. The only consequence is that you have to add to your project settings a few libs (base, core, etc and in a proper order) instead of an only big one. Take a look at `<wxWidgets dir>\lib`

Addin `mingw\bin` to the PATH is an option. C::B doesn't need it. It's the command box who needs it. If you don't want to pollute the PATH var then you have to add it each time you open a command box to use the compiler:

Execute `PATH=%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin` (where MinGW is where you installed the compiler) before using the compiler in this command box.

Comment: Ok it built fine but when i try to run the wx widgets template on codeblocks it says         `||=== Build: Debug in hey well (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\include\wx\platform.h|148|fatal error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
`

Comment: That's another issue, which requires another question specifiying all the steps and options you did/selected in the wxWidgets template in CB. Say also the CB version.

Comment: Man , thanks for your help, I’ll create another question

Comment: @dami  Keep in mind that MONOLITHIC option is a must IF upi want to become CodeBlocks supporter. Otherwise you can drop it. Also since you are on Windows I suggest to use SHARED = 0 option. That way you will need to distribute only 1 executable and the run-time libraries.